# Convert integer value to string using JSTL/EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How do I correct this statement:

```
${model.myHashtable[model.data.id]}.
```

myHashtable is defined as

```
Hashtable<String, String>
```

But, `${model.data.id}` returns an `int`.

I tried to do something like

```
${model.myHashtable['model.data.id']}
```

But it does not work. Any other ideas, aside from changing the type of `id` to `String`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Set it as body of `<c:set>`. It will implicitly be converted to `String`.

```
<c:set var="idAsString">${model.data.id}</c:set>
<c:out value="${model.myHashtable[idAsString]}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this out tomorrow. :)

Comment: I think this is the 3rd time this month one of your answers has helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the best way to compare a string to a number in EL without having to worry about an exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

`${''.concat(model.data.id)}` works for me,you may try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use org.apache.commons.collections4.map.CaseInsensitiveMap both String "1" and int 1 are the same key;

Answer (score 0):

In JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!-- lines of code... -->

<fmt:parseNumber var = "id_value" type = "number" value = "${model.data.id}" />
<c:out value = "${id_value}" />
```

Answer (score -2):

The $ {model.data.id} returns an integer, use Hashtable <Integer, String>, which solves my problem. If the id is a number, then <c:set> is useless.