# Property 'someproperty' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I am getting this error and I can not figure out where the problem might be. The "userid" column is in the database and is in the bean. Does anyone have any idea?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /user.jsp     at line 24  

21:   
22:     <form method="POST" action="AdminServlet" name="frmAddUser">  
23:         User ID : <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="userid"  
24:             value="<c:out value="${user.userid}" />" />   
Username : <input  
25:             type="text" name="firstName"  
26:             value="<c:out value="${user.firstName}" />" />   
LastName : <input  
27:             type="text" name="lastName"  

root cause   

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userid' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you set the User Parameter on you JSP? Can you include the Code?

Comment: `user` is not an object but just a `String`

Comment: do you need to see the user bean?

Comment: @ZenunKastrioti Just show where `user` is defined and what it's supposed to be (so yeah, I guess the bean)

Comment: I am not able to post here all the code however:

Comment: public class User {

 private int userid;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private Date dob;
 private String email;
 private boolean admin;
 private String password;

 public int getUserid() {
  return userid;
 }

 public void setUserid(int userid) {
  this.userid = userid;
 }
........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is basicaly telling you that `${user}` is an ordinary `java.lang.String`. According to [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), it has indeed no `getUserid()` method representing an `userid` property.

Make sure that you're setting a concrete `User` instance in the desired scope instead of a plain vanilla `String`. As you haven't shown anywhere in the question how you're preparing the scoped variable, it isn't possible to give a targeted answer on that, but it should at least look something like this:

```
User user = userService.find(id);
request.setAttribute("user", user); // and thus not e.g. setAttribute("user", "user") or something.
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the following should be the case, according to me

- The `userid` data-type is not matching with the one corresponding in the bean. It might be `integer` in db.
- The property is not defined in the bean class. The name might be different, and you must be inferring it to be `userid`.

Comment: the userid data-type is integer actually. what can I do here to fix this?

Comment: So then as said, in java class, it is being defined as `String`. Make a change at either side.

Comment: The exception isn't telling that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a `<c:set var="user">${user}</c:set>` anywhere on the jsp?

According to [Response 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576131/convert-integer-value-to-string-using-jstl-el) on another question, JSP does an implicit conversion to a string when you set the var in the JSP.