# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'user'

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

**I am working with spring webflow**
**My jsp page is**

```
<!-- header -->
<%@include file="../shared/flows-header.jsp"%>

<div class = "container">


<div class = "row">

<div class = col-sm-6>

    <div class = "panel panel-primary">

        <div class = "panel-heading">

            <h4>Personal Details</h4>

        </div>

        <div class = "panel-body">

            <!-- to display personal details -->
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h3>Name : <strong>${registerModel.user.firstname} ${registerModel.user.lastname}</strong></h3>
                        <h4>Email : <strong>${registerModel.user.email}</strong></h4>
                        <h4>Contact : <strong>${registerModel.user.contactNumber}</strong></h4>
                        <h4>Role : <strong>${registerModel.user.role}</strong></h4>

                    </div>

                    <!-- anchor tag to move to personal details page to edit -->
                    <p>
                        <a href = "${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId_personal" class = "btn btn-primary">Edit</a>        
                    </p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<div class = col-sm-6>

    <div class = "panel panel-primary">

        <div class = "panel-heading">

            <h4>Billing Address</h4>

        </div>

        <div class = "panel-body">

            <!-- to display billing address -->
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>${registerModel.billing.addressLineOne}, </p>
                        <p>${registerModel.billing.addressLineTwo}, </p>
                        <p>${registerModel.billing.city} -  ${registerModel.billing.postalCode}, </p>
                        <p>${registerModel.billing.state}</p>
                        <p>${registerModel.billing.country}</p>
                    </div>      

            <!-- anchor tag to move to billing address page to edit -->
            <p>
                <a href = "${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId_billing" class = "btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class = "row">

    <div class = "col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">

        <div class = "text-center">

            <!-- anchor tag to move to success page -->
            <a href = "${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId_submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Confirm Submission</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<!-- footer -->
<%@include file="../shared/flows-footer.jsp"%>
```

**My signup-flow.xml page is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

    <var  name = "user" class = "model.entity.User" />
    <var  name = "billing" class = "model.entity.Address" />

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="'registerHandler.init()'" result = "flowScope.registerModel" />
    </on-start>


    <!-- start state -->
    <view-state id = "personal" view = "flows/register/signup-personal" model = "'user'"><!-- model value is used as modelAttribute in spring form -->
        <transition on = "billing" to = "billing" /><!-- to billing view state -->
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="'registerHandler.addUser(flowScope.registerModel , user)'" />
        </on-exit>
     </view-state>

    <view-state id = "billing" view = "flows/register/signup-billing" model = "'billing'">
        <transition on = "personal" to = "personal" />
        <transition on = "confirm" to = "confirm" />
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="'registerHandler.addBilling(flowScope.registerModel , billing)'" />
        </on-exit>
     </view-state>

    <view-state id = "confirm" view = "flows/register/signup-confirm" model = "flowScope.registerModel">
        <transition on = "personal" to = "personal" />
        <transition on = "billing" to = "billing" />
        <transition on = "submit" to = "submit" />  
     </view-state>

    <action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression="'registerHandler.saveAll(flowScope.registerModel)'" />
        <transition on = "success" to = "success" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- end state -->
    <end-state id = "home" view = "externalRedirect:contextRelative:/" />
    <end-state id = "success" view = "flows/register/signup-success" />


    <!-- global transition -->
    <global-transitions>
        <transition on = "home" to = "home"/>
    </global-transitions>

</flow>
```

**The error stack trace is **

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to
>   /OnlineShoppingFE/views/flows/register/signup-confirm.jsp:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'confirm' of flow 'register'    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'confirm' of flow 'register'    at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:573)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:253)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception
>   occurred rendering view org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView:
>   name 'flows/register/signup-confirm'; URL
>   [/views/flows/register/signup-confirm.jsp]    at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:220)
>     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)    at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
>     ... 50 more Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does
>   not have the property 'user'.     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:196)
>     ... 55 more Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class
>   'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'user'.     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568)  at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)    at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.views.flows.register.signup_002dconfirm_jsp._jspService(signup_002dconfirm_jsp.java:230)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
>     ... 75 more

**RegisterModel class is**

```
package flow.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import model.entity.Address;
import model.entity.User;

public class RegisterModel implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    private Address billing;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Address getBilling() {
        return billing;
    }

    public void setBilling(Address billing) {
        this.billing = billing;
    }


}
```

**RegisterHandler class**

```
package handler;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import flow.model.RegisterModel;
import model.dao.IUserDAO;
import model.entity.Address;
import model.entity.Cart;
import model.entity.User;

@Component
public class RegisterHandler {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    public RegisterModel init()
    {
        System.out.println(new RegisterModel().toString());
        return (new RegisterModel());
    }

    public void addUser(RegisterModel registerModel,User user)
    {
        registerModel.setUser(user);
    }

    public void addBilling(RegisterModel registerModel,Address billing)
    {
        registerModel.setBilling(billing);
    }

    public String saveAll(RegisterModel model)
    {
        String transitionValue = "success";

        //fetch user
        User user = model.getUser();

        if(user.getRole().equals("ROLE"))
        {
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            cart.setUser(user);
            user.setCart(cart);
        }

        //save user
        userDAO.addUser(user);

        //get address
        Address billing = model.getBilling();   
        billing.setUserId(user.getId());
        billing.setBilling(true);

        //save the address
        userDAO.addAddress(billing);

        return transitionValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your `model` class also

Comment: posted my model class as requested @Swati

Comment: Does your *User* class is public or not and also getter setter?

Comment: yes User class is public and it also has getter setter for all the fields @Swati

Comment: Just try with **${user.firstname}** don’t use **registerModel** and see if it prints something or not, because i didn’t find anything wrong in your code , also maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807683/property-someproperty-not-found-on-type-java-lang-string) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several possible misunderstandings there, but I think the main one is that you're using single quotes around attributes that you should not. The one causing this particular problem is:

```
<evaluate expression="'registerHandler.init()'" result = "flowScope.registerModel" />
```

You're putting into `flowScope.registerModel`, the String value "registerHandler.init()", not the results of calling `registerHandler.init()`.

Instead, remove the single quotes like this:

```
<evaluate expression="registerHandler.init()" result = "flowScope.registerModel" />
```

Same for the later references like:

```
   <view-state id = "billing" view = "flows/register/signup-billing" model = "'billing'">
```

This should also not have the single quotes around "billing":

```
   <view-state id = "billing" view = "flows/register/signup-billing" model = "billing">
```

(Also, by declaring `<var>`s "user" and "billing", those are automatically put on flow scope, so you can refer to them in JSPs directly like `${user.firstname}`.)