# Accessing an element via variable alias in jsp

Tags: jsp, hashmap, jstl, el

I've been hung up on this issue for a while now, and it's driving me insane.

I have a hash that looks like this in java:

```
hash.get("1") => "Hello"
hash.get("2") => "Hello"
hash.get("3") => "Hello"
hash.get("4") => "Hello"
```

This works in JSP to get "1":

```
${hash["1"]}
```

But this doesn't:

```
<c:forEach begin='1' end='4' var='index'>
    ${index}
    ${hash[index]}
</c:forEach>
```

Why can't I access an element in a hash in JSP by a variable's alias? I can use a foreach loop on the hash, but I don't want to do that. Is it possible, at all, to just access a hash element by a variable-aliased key?

Comment: ${hash[index + '']} should work. index is a number, not a string.

Comment: Why do you have a `Map<String, V>` instead of `Map<Long, V>` in first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
 <c:set var="stringId">${index}</c:set>
 ${ratingsCount[stringId]}
```

Source: [Convert integer value to string using JSTL/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576131/convert-integer-value-to-string-using-jstl-el/3576485#3576485)

Comment: In name of our cc-by-sa license, it would be fair if you cited/linked the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576131/convert-integer-value-to-string-using-jstl-el/3576485#3576485) where you found this answer.

Comment: Sorry, linked source.